# What could cause Citrix Xenapp to stop streaming applications after the server's IP address changed?

Tags: citrix, xenapp

We have a Citrix XenApp 5.0 server running on Windows 2008, and today we moved ISPs so our IP addresses changed.  The IP addresses have propagated, the XenApp server is running, and internally we can connect to the server, choose an app, and have it streamed without issue.  Externally we are only able to authenticate to the server and choose an app, but the app never launches in the client.

I'm guessing there's a hand-off between the part of XenApp that authenticates a user and shows what apps they can launch, and the part that does the app streaming, and that second part is hard-coded to use an the old ip address.  Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 2):

Ahh - the benefit of a second pair of eyes!  A coworker helped find it under Citrix Web Interface Management.  The IP address was hard-coded in the Services sites section in there.  To get there I clicked XenApp Services Sites >  > Secure Access > Edit secure access settings > Next > and then edited the address translation there.

Comment: Mark this as your accepted answer, so this question doesn't crop up on the front page as unanswered.